# Affected rows for ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, connection

With Rails 4.1.1, using mysql2 adapter:

I am using an ActiveRecord [`connection`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/connection) to execute a multiple insert in a MySQL table:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute %Q{
    INSERT INTO table (`user_id`, `item_id`) 
    SELECT 1, id FROM items WHERE items.condition IS NOT NULL
}
```

This works fine, do the job, and returns `nil`.

Is there a way to get the number of **affected rows**?
(avoiding the need to execute another query)

I have found the documentation of the [`execute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute) method somewhat sparse.

Comment: Better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45677098/165673

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `connection.update` method which executes expression and returns affected rows count.

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  .update("INSERT INTO accounts (`name`) VALUES ('first'), ('second')")

=> 2
```

Rails v4.2.7 doc - http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-update

Rails latest doc -  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-update

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way to get the number of affected rows using the mysql2 adapter.  Put this in a file that gets loaded by your app:

```ruby
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
  def affected_rows
    @connection.affected_rows
  end
end
```

Then you will be able to run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.affected_rows` to get the number of affected rows.

Comment: and how about multi-threading and connection pools? Can one be sure affected rows are returned from the same connection?

Comment: @akostadinov Current thread is the connection's sole holder until you check it back in to the pool. That's the whole point of the connection pool.