# Affected rows for ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to get the number of affected rows resulting from a SQL operation using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552542/affected-rows-for-activerecordbase-connection-execute) for MySQL adapters, but it doesn't work with Postgres.

Alternatively, if there's a way to get the SQL text response (e.g. "UPDATE 126"), that would work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cmd_tuples` method:

```
sql = "UPDATE users SET updated_at = '#{DateTime.now}' WHERE id = 1"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).cmd_tuples
# => 1
```

Documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.17.1/PG%2FResult:cmd_tuples